# Nonetype has no attribute get and return self.func(args) error with tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am fairly new to Python, and I am trying to create a program using Tkinter. The Errors I usually get are:
return self.func(*args) and 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
I've created a simplified version of my code.
Any help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Entry = Entry(root).pack()

def generic():
labellabel = Label(root, text=Entry.get()).pack()

Button = Button(root, text="test", command=generic).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename Entry. If `Entry = Entry(...)`, you are overwriting an existing tk class. try `entry = Entry(...)`. Same for Button! Also before labellabel there should be 4 spaces.

Your variables are the return values of `.pack()`, which is none! Try:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

def generic():
    labellabel = Label(root, text=entry.get()).pack()

button = Button(root, text="test", command=generic)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

By the way your code should work in Python 3.x.